# Difference in type of lambda when using [] and [this]

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have a class db_interface. And defined a lambda type:

```
typedef void (*db_interface_lambda)();
```

When I create lambda in class in such way: `[](){ /* do something */ }`, it has good type (db_interface_lambda), but when I use `[this](){ /* do something */ }`, the compiler starts to shout at me.

```
cannot convert ‘db_interface::db_interface(std::ifstream&)::<lambda()>’ to ‘std::map<std::basic_string<char>, void (*)()>::mapped_type {aka void (*)()}’ in assignment
```

How to solve that problem? What is the correct type?

Comment: "*And defined a lambda type: `typedef void (*db_interface_lambda)();`*" That _not_ a lambda type, that is a function pointer type.

Comment: As everybody suggested, the best solution is to use std::function. `typedef std::function<void()> db_interface_lambda`. Both lambdas in your example are convertible to this type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because lambdas are only implicitly convertible to function pointers *if and only if* they do not capture anything.

`§5.1.2 [expr.prim.lambda] p6`

> The closure type for a *lambda-expression* with no *lambda-capture* (`[]` is empty) has a public non-virtual non-explicit const conversion function to pointer to function having the same parameter and return types as the closure type’s function call operator.

Btw, what you `typedef`'d there is a function pointer, not a lambda type. Lambda expressions have a *unique, unnamed, nonunion class type*. You can not name them.

`§5.1.2 [expr.prim.lambda] p3`

> The type of the *lambda-expression* (which is also the type of the closure object) is a unique, unnamed nonunion class type

Answer (score 7):

You're trying to call something that wants a function pointer. A captureless lambda can be converted to a function pointer automatically, but once you write `[this]` it ceases to be captureless - you're capturing `this`, so it's an error.

The solution is to change the type to be a `std::function`, not a pointer to a function. `std::function` erases the type of the "functor" it "wraps" so you can still pass a function pointer as well as a lamba with a capture.

Answer (score 6):

Lambdas that do not capture anything are essentially *free functions*, and thus they are convertible to ordinary function pointers.

Lambdas that *do* capture are essentially full classes, and they cannot simply be converted to a free-function pointer. (A capturing lambda is really essentially the same predicate functor class that you would have written in C++ before we had lambdas.)

Either version of lambda **is** convertible to `std::function<void()>`, which is what the mapped type of your map should be.

Comment: *state-less* and *free* functions are different things, `struct x { void operator()() {} };` is clearly stateless and not a free function but rather a functor class. As @awoodland points out, a lambda that does not capture can be *converted* to a free function of similar signature, but that is far from it being *essentially* a free function. A lambda is *essentially* a functor (function class)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Well, I was hand-waving a bit, but that said, any sensible optimizing compiler will actually implement your `x()()` as a free function -- it's just that in the case of `x` you don't have access to this through the language, while in the case of the non-capturing lambda you more or less do (i.e. you have access to a *conversion*, however that is implemented under the hood -- possibly a no-op).